# append values to a HashMap <String , ArraList<Object>>

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am trying to create a simple HashMap , which will have a String as a key , and for each key there's an ArrayList of Objects .

The problem with the solution I came up with is at the end of the loop , I get only one value (Object ) in the ArrayList ...

I tried using the MultiValueMap in Apache Commons but my IDE protests , it says it is deprecated

```
//filter products by supplier
            for(String nume:SuppliersNames){

                ArrayList<Order.Product> gol = new ArrayList<>();
                SuppliersMap.put(nume,gol);

                //we make a copy of the products collection so we can iterate it and filter elements by supplier

                ArrayList<Orders.Order.Product> interm = new ArrayList<Orders.Order.Product>(products);

                Iterator<Orders.Order.Product> iter = interm.iterator();

                while (iter.hasNext()){

                    Orders.Order.Product curent = iter.next();

                    if(curent.getSupplier()== nume){

                        SuppliersMap.get(nume).add(curent);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "my IDE protests" ?

Comment: I might be overlooking something here but you shouldn't need to copy to filter. Can you use streams?

Comment: The issue with your code is that you put in your map a new `gol` on each loop. So you replace the value `ArrayList`. You should check if the `nume` key already exists, and add it just if not.

Comment: Apart from that it might be more concise to use Java8 streams for this, the problem might be the check `curent.getSupplier() == nume`. You are comparing for identity here and this is probably not what you want. Try changing this into `curent.getSupplier().equals(nume)` and see what happens.

Comment: @dpr The logic to check for existing key is above the snippet I posted , anyway Thank You ! The .equals() did the trick !  Post as answer so I can mark it please.

Comment: [Guava](https://github.com/google/guava)'s [`Multimap`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) type is excellent, use that instead of Apache Commons which is very dated.

Comment: @user1311432 would you mind to accept the answer as well in order to mark this question as solved. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments the problem is very likely the check `curent.getSupplier() == nume`. You are comparing for identity here and this is probably not what you want. Try changing this to `curent.getSupplier().equals(nume)` and see what happens.

Furthermore there is no need to create a local copy of the `products` collection as you are not modifying this collection in the posted snippet.

Using Java8 streams your code could be changed to this:

```
for (String name : suppliersNames) {
    List<Product> gol = products.stream().filter(p -> p.getSupplier().equals(name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    suppliersNames.put(name, gol);
}
```